# How do I count specific processes on Mac OS X?

Tags: macos, bash, shell, command-line, openbsd

Using a Mac, what would be the best way to count the number of instances of a particular process I am running? This is for a script I am writing to find the number of `ffmpeg` processes running on my machine.

Should I be using `top` here? `ps aux|grep ffmpeg`? What would be the best way to get the number?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

grep -c will count occurrences:

```
count=`ps aux | grep -v "grep" | grep -c ffmpeg`
echo $count
```

Comment: try `ps -C ffmpeg` to avoid grepping (and catching grep itself, or `man ffmpeg`).

Comment: @userunknown: in a mac: `ps -C /usr/sbin/syslogd` gives you `ps: illegal argument ffmpeg`

Comment: Oh, I guess syslogd or ffmpeg on both sides - invocation and error is meant? However, did you look, whether there is another way to invoke ps with a name to look for on MacOS?

Answer (score 3):

`ps aux | grep ffmpeg | wc -l` will get you the number of processes that mention the phrase 'ffmpeg' you'll need to minus 1 on this value as `ps aux | grep ffmpg` is a process also.

Comment: The customary way to avoid the -1 is to craft a regex which doesn't match itself. `ps aux | grep -c '[f]fmpeg'`

Comment: @tripleee: try `ps -C ffmpeg` instead, and in contrast try both commands, while running `man ffmpeg` meanwhile.

Comment: As per comments to other answers, `ps -C` appears to be unsupported on the Mac. You can fix that by anchoring the `grep` regex suitably.

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for the program called "wc" -- "wc -l" will count lines for you.

"man wc" for details.

Answer (score 1):

You can try the [killall](http://linux.die.net/man/1/killall) command on the Mac:

```
$ killall -s ffmpg
kill -TERM 20148
kill -TERM 20146
kill -TERM 20140
```

The `-s` means just list what you'd do, but don't actually kill any processes. Pipe it to `wc`, and you should get your result:

```
$ killall -s ffmpg | wc -l
3
```

In a shell script, you can do something like this:

```
num_of_processes=$(killall -s ffmpg | wc -l)
```

Answer (score 1):

[`pgrep`](http://sourceforge.net/projects/proctools/):

```
$ pgrep -c ffmpeg
```

If you don't use `pgrep` then mere `grep` might produce false positives.

To avoid it you could try `-C` option:

```
$ ps -C ffmpeg -o pid= | wc -l
```

Check that your `ps` version interprets it correctly.

Comment: pgrep is not native on a mac, is it?

Comment: @Paulo Scardine: `pgrep` supports mac. Click on the link. I don't know whether it is installed by default.

Comment: downvote because even after `brew install proctools` I run `pgrep -c ffmpeg` and get back `pgrep: illegal option -- c`

Comment: @cwd: the command works on Linux. I trust that you are capable to find appreciate arguments for `pgrep`  on OS X.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian - but the op is asking specifically about mac. furthermore there do not appear to be any "appreciate arguments" on OS X

Comment: @cwd the question has Linux tag too. I don't believe that you can't use `pgrep` on OS  X (in the worst case, use `| wc -l` like shown in the 2nd command).

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian - actually the second command will not work either because the `-C` flag is not valid for `ps` on OS X. fixed the tags on the question per your suggestion.

Comment: @cwd  if you can't combine `pgrep + wc`; ask

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian - its not about "being able to combine `pgrep + wc`" - I'm explaining my downvote / letting you know that your answer needs improvement. you offer two command combinations, neither of which work for the system in question.

Comment: @cwd: as I said, it works on Linux and the question has Linux tag.

Comment: for me `pgrep -c` works in OS X (Sierra) but only in a login shell? When I try to do it in a script, it doesn't work.